# URL path for css background wont work in meteor template

Tags: html, css, mongodb, meteor

I am making a web application that uses meteor js as a framework. In it I have a template with some html elements and then a style tag that changes the background of an html element in the template.  I set up some code that makes the template display for every document in a mongo database I set up with meteor, and as soon as I did this the url for the background change in the css wont register anymore.  It will work if I put in a color like "black" but if I give it a specific path like /images/image.jpg it will not work, even though this used to work just fine.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @sbswim i refined my question to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099293/how-do-i-insert-a-meteor-template-that-contains-double-quotes-in-a-place-where-t