# How do I insert a meteor template that contains double quotes in a place where those double quotes are needed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor

In my meteor web app I am trying to change the background of a certain element conditionally with this code:

```
.popular-games{
  background-image: url({{background}});
}
```

{{background}} being the path it should follow to find the image. This will not work though because the url path needs quotes, and when I put in quotes in negates {{background}}. I've tried putting the quotes into the source where {{background}} is coming from with this code:

```
background: "\"images/gameArt/fallout4.jpg\""
```

trying to add in the quotes, but this still does not work for some reason.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I am not sure that I follow. Are you trying to write CSS with Meteor Blaze? Perhaps you are trying to do something that should be done by either changing a `class` (if there is a specific set of backgrounds) or setting it via the HTML element's `style` property?

Comment: Try to use `background-image: url('../Images/someImage.jpg');`

Comment: Try to add this css command, within javascript, maybe you can escape the quotes: (".popular-games").css('background-image','your url here');

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the style in your html like this:

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{imagePath}}');"></div>
```

If the file path you return is correct, it will work.